# Cryptocoincharts API jquery/json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

First time user of Stack here and I am wanting to know how to turn their rest/json api into a jquery/json in order to speed up load times.

This is their code,

```
$pair = "ltc_usd";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.cryptocoincharts.info/v2/api/tradingPair/".$pair);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$rawData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$data = json_decode($rawData);

echo "<pre>";
echo "Price of ".$data->id.": ".$data->price."\n";
echo "Trade this pair on ".$data->best_market."\n";
echo "</pre>";
```

and this is my version of theirs,

```
<tr>
   <td>LiteCoin</td>
   <td>LTC</td>
   <td class="center">
      <?php
         $pair = "ltc_btc";
         $curl = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.cryptocoincharts.info/v2/api/tradingPair/".$pair);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         $rawData = curl_exec($curl);
         curl_close($curl);
         $data = json_decode($rawData);
         if($data->price > 0) { echo $data->price." Btc</td>"; } else { echo "0 or Unlisted</td>"; } if($data->best_market != "") { echo "<td>".$data->best_market."</td>"; } else { echo "<td>Unlisted</td>"; } if($data->volume_btc > 0) { echo "<td>".$data->volume_btc." Btc</td>"; } else { echo "<td>0.00 Btc</td>"; }
         ?>
   </td>
</tr>
```

The reason being is the current code is really slow, for example http://cryptodatabase.net/coins-b takes 25 seconds to load.

Could someone help me with this please and thank you.

Comment: Still looking for help with this, it would be appreciated greatly.